# Term or Title That Embraces the Juxtaposition of Work and Fun

Tags: nouns, adjectives, terminology, titles

I'm looking for a clever way to describe someone who likes to be positive and have fun but who is also serious about getting work done. The phrase "work hard, play hard" comes to mind, but I'm not fond of the word "play" in this context. So, is there another term or phrase that embraces this juxtaposition and can ideally be used as a pseudo-title for this person during an upcoming team building activity I'm planning? It doesn't have to be a single-word, but short and sweet is preferred. Nouns or adjectives are acceptable in this case.

Comment: Perhaps the sports-focused [**all-rounder**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all-rounder) is not good enough to post as an answer.

Comment: How about "mullet"? :P The definition of it is "business in the front, party in the back".

Comment: Love it, hahaha.

Comment: ... Ardent Jack.

Answer (score 1):

A clever way to approach this:

Part 1: Title of respect

Admiral:the commander in chief of a navy;  a commissioned officer in the navy or coast guard who ranks above a vice admiral and whose insignia is four stars

Captain: a military leader : the commander of a unit or a body of troops

Chief: accorded highest rank or office

Above definitions Merriam Webster

Part 2: Work Hard

Efficient: someone who is efficient works well and quickly and is good at organizing their work in the way that gets the best results

Productivite: working hard and producing or achieving a lot

Diligent: someone who is diligent works very hard and very carefully

Above definitions from Macmillan Dictionary

Part 3- Play Hard

Leisure: freedom provided by the cessation of activities

Entertainment: amusement or diversion provided especially by performers

Recreation: refreshment of strength and spirits after work

Above definitions from Merriam Webster

End Result:

Admiral Productive Entertainer
CELO- Chief Effective and Leisure Officer
Captain of Dilligence and Recreation

Answer (score 1):

How about...

> ***[Dynamic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dynamic)***
>
> 2. (of a person) positive in attitude and full of energy and new ideas.
>    *a dynamic young advertising executive*

This can be said of someone who has the energy to carry on their work as if it is a fun thing to do, while very dedicated and tuned in.

Maybe also...

> ***Lighthearted yet dedicated***
>
> [*Lighthearted*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lighthearted)
>
> 1. (1.1) (of a person or their behavior) cheerful and carefree.
>    *excited, lighthearted chatter*
>
> *[Dedicated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dedicated)*
>
> 1. (of a person) devoted to a task or purpose; having single-minded loyalty or integrity.
>    *a team of dedicated doctors*

This, to me, would imply someone who is a hard worker with a light personality to enjoy the work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a person who can be described as a **Type A Personality**

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_A_and_Type_B_personality_theory
>
> Type A and Type B personality hypothesis describes two contrasting personality types. In this hypothesis, personalities that are more competitive, highly organized, ambitious, impatient, highly aware of time management and/or aggressive are labeled Type A, while more relaxed, less 'neurotic', 'frantic', 'explainable', personalities are labeled Type B.

In colloquial use, calling someone a "Type A person" implies they need to "be the best" and achieve excellence at work, or win #1 when playing a game, and they are unsatisfied with just "getting by" in either domain.

While "Type A and B" personality theory has been mostly scientifically discredited and replaced by the [five factor personality model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) in the modern research, the phrase "Type A personality" remains commonly understood in colloquial use to mean someone who has a "work hard, play hard" attitude.

Comment: Type A personality, as described by Friedman and Rosenman back in the 50's, refers to individuals who are highly competitive, ambitious, rigidly organized and by no means interested in having fun.  Type A personality was for some time considered a risk factor for coronary heart disease.